# Using ReactiveCocoa with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I've used RAC with objective-c but now I'm not able to use with swift.

I downloaded and included ReactiveCocoaBindings.swift on my project.
**[Here](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Swift-RAC-Macros)** the temporary macros.

I need to **observe** an array "linked" to a collection view.

With objective-c I can do it with this code:

```
[RACObserve(self, self.myArray) subscribeNext:^(NSArray* arr) {
    [collectionView reloadData];
}];
```

In ReactiveCocoa bridge file there is:

```
public func RACObserve(target: NSObject!, keyPath: String) -> RACSignal {
    return target.rac_valuesForKeyPath(keyPath, observer: target)
}
```

So.. how can I use it?

Answer (score 3):

```
RACObserve(self, "myArray").subscribeNext { [weak self] arr in
    // cast arr to array if you want to use it inside block replace it with _ symbol otherwise
    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Remember that, if `myArray` property is defined in swift file it should have `dynamic` modifier